# Calculate the intermediate value between 3 numbers (pseudocode)

Tags: numbers, pseudocode

How I can find the intermediate value between 3 integers? It is possible without using external functions or many conditional?

Comment: Do you mean the value in the middle?

Comment: Yes, exactly the intermediate value between 3 numbers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

for three numbers, look for the min and max.
then look for the number that is neither min nor max :D

```
int a=100;
int b=200;
int c=300;

int max = (a>b)? ( (a>c)?a: (b>c)? b:c ):  ((b>c)?b: c );
int min = (a<b)? ( (a<c)?a: (b<c)? b:c ):  ((b<c)?b: c );
int result = (a != min && a!= max)? a: (b !=min && b !=max)? b: c;
```